# Input EditText(Type:Number) into array[]

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an EditText (input type:numberDecimal),that I want to keep adding values with save them to an Array.
how can i do this ?

for an example:

```
EditText:"1234"
Array[0]=1;
Array[1]=2;
Array[2]=3;
Array[3]=4;
```

Thanks...

Comment: Use a textchanged listener on edittext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ArrayList instead, since you don't know exact number of numbers user going to input.

```
ArraList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    et.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            try
            {
                char currentChar = arg0.charAt(arg1); // currently typed character
                list.add(currentChar);// Add the character to the list.
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // error
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: tnx a lot...but not work for me...! problam is that " list.add(currentChar) " doesnt work with ArrayList<String> , so i changed the Array to <Charset>,but the problem still is not solved.if as an example EditText is:"1234" , The Array fill with : {1-1-1-1} !!!

Comment: use list.add(String.valueOf(currentChar))

Answer (score 2):

TextWatcher is a useful class provided by the Android Developer API. It can be used to watch a input text field and you can instantly update data on other views. It can be useful for counting the number of characters entered in the text field instantly.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

        et.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                try
                {
                    char currentChar = arg0.charAt(arg1); // currently typed character
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    // error
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }
        });
```

http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/android-textwatcher-example.html

Comment: so useful for future projects...tnx :)